# How to convert a data row into an object array?

Tags: c#, arrays, datarow

I have a data row which I would like to make into an object array since to add it to my data table I need an object array. What I have made up to now is this...

```
data_table.Rows.Add(data_row.ToArray<object>());
```

but this does not work since this does not give an object array, at least thats what my compiler tells me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ItemArray` property on `DataRow` type.

```
object[] arr = data_row.ItemArray;
```

Comment: So quick and easy

Comment: Doesn't `arr` need to have a `$` or `@` in front of it, or is `object[]` taking care of that for that line of code?

Answer (score 0):

You could always make an extension method to DataRow like this:

```
public static class DataRowExtension 
{
    // Class for: Conversion to object[]
    public static object[] ToObjectArray(this DataRow dataRow)
    {
        // Identifiers used are:
        int columnCount = dataRow.Table.Columns.Count;
        object[] objectArray = new object[columnCount];

        // Check the row is not empty
        if (columnCount == 0)
        {
            return null;
        }

        // Go through the row to add each element to the array
        for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++)
        {
            objectArray[i] = dataRow[i];
        }

        // Return the object array
        return objectArray;
    }
}
```

Extension methods are great.

Comment: Thanks but this is too complicated for me